# Argparse Positional arguments or Default

Tags: python, argparse

I want to run the cli like `myscript A B C`, which should return Namespace(my_attribute=['A', 'B', 'C']) or `myscript` which should return the default when no args are specified ie Namespace(my_attribute=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

Is this possible?

- nargs='+' requires at least 1 command line argument or raises an error
- nargs='?' takes 1 or 0 args
- nargs='*' seems like it should work, but doesn't produce the default list specified in add_argument()

I have the below at the moment.

```
parser.add_argument(
    dest='my_attribute',
    choices=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
    nargs='*',
    default=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
)
```

**Edit

for example: This works, but I have to specify `-attr` before A B. I don't want to have to use `-attr`

```
parser.add_argument(
    '-attr',
    dest='my_attribute',
    choices=['A','B', 'C', 'D'],
    nargs='+',
    default=['A','B', 'C', 'D'],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error message are you getting?

When I try your code I get:

> error: argument my_attribute: invalid choice: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] (choose from 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

It is trying to use the default, but it is testing the whole thing against your choices.  You expect it to either not to test the default at all, or to test each element of the list separately.

Without the `choices`, the `*` positional does work.

As I noted in my first answer, a `*` positional requires some special handling.  A `*` optional does not.

A kludge is to use `default='A'`.  This passes the choices test.  The resulting namespace will be `Namespace(my_attribute='A')`.  This isn't the expected list, but it's easy to test and replace after parsing.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    dest='my_attribute',
    choices=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
    nargs='*',
    default='A',
)
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.my_attribute=='A':
    args.my_attribute=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print args
```

---

There is a bug report (several years old) on this topic:

http://bugs.python.org/issue9625
'argparse: Problem with defaults for variable nargs when using choices'

There's a proposed patch would perform the 'choices' test on each item of a list default.  With that `argparse` should run your example fine.  But there's quite a backlog of `argparse` patches, so I don't expect to see this fix anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `nargs=4`? E.g.

```
parser.add_argument(
    dest='my_attribute',
    choices=list(itertools.permutations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']))
    nargs=4,
    default=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
)
```

Note the permutations in choces, as you might need the following choices:

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
'A', 'D', 'C', 'B'
...
'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'
```

Replace `permutations` with `combinations` if needed.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to specify 3 args all the time here? I want to be able to specify between 0 and 4 args, returning the default when I don't specify any args.

Comment: With this `choices`, the usage is: `usage: PROG [-h] {} {} {} {}`.

Comment: Hm... `list(...)` ? But anyway, there are too many choices to show. I guess they could be omitted here if the choices are required for showing 'choices', not filtering the argument.

Comment: There are 2 issues with `choices` object.  For testing it just need a `in` test (e.g. `'A'` in choices`).  For usage `argparse` iterates over `choices` to compose a `{...}` string.